# In DB2 PL/SQL anonymous block declare local variables and declare continue handler results in error?

Tags: db2, handler, sql-pl

I am trying to make a simple script that handles errors from statements that are ok to fail gracefully. This is for DB2 v10.5 (Linux)

Example create a table and handle if table already exists

```
begin 
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '42710' BEGIN END; 
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE T(c1 INT)'; 
end
/
```

This works ok

Now I had a slightly more complex block that originally used local variables and I was trying to added the DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER and I could not get it to compile. Simplifying the problem I found that by adding a declare statement before the begin fails if I have the Handler line (note I am not using the localVariable here, but it fails just by adding that statement in. If I run same statement without DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER, it also runs ok

```
declare 
  localVariable  INT;
begin 
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '42710' BEGIN END; 
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE T(c1 INT)'; 
end
/
```

Resulting error code

> Error report: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601,
>   SQLERRMC=end;end;BEGIN, DRIVER=3.68.61

Comment: Do not mix PL/SQL and DB2 SQL PL syntax. Choose either and use that consistently.

Comment: What is the correct DB2 SQL syntax? If I try BEGIN
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '42710' BEGIN END;
    DECLARE variable1 INT;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE T(c1 INT)'; 
END
/ - this also results in an 42601 error.

Comment: Did you try the manuals? Variable declarations must come before handler declarations. http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0004239.html?cp=SSEPGG_9.7.0%2F2-10-6-49&lang=en

Comment: Thanks, do you want to post your comments as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be mixing up PL/SQL and DB2 SQL PL syntax. A PL/SQL block has the `DECLARE` section before `BEGIN...END`, as in your second example. If you use that, all your declaration must be in the `DECLARE` section.

When you use SQL PL compound SQL syntax, there is no separate `DECLARE` section, but instead all `DECLARE` *statements* must appear within the `BEGIN...END` block *before* any executable statements. Note that the order of `DECLARE` statements is also important. For example, condition handler declarations must appear after the variable declarations. You can find the exact [compound SQL syntax in the manual](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0004239.html?cp=SSEPGG_9.7.0%2F2-10-6-49&lang=en).